# How to create a function to calculate the difference in time (which is in the form of numpy array)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have two numpy arrays from a .csv file which contain times (opening and closing times of a store). I have to define a function which calculates the duration of opening time. I am having a lot of trouble solving this and have spent hours trying things.

I have tried using datetime.datetime, and timedelta, etc. The code I'm mentioning is from a question I've asked before but deleted it later.

```
def parse_time(time_string):
    #This func returns the correct datetime object if the time string can be parsed
    #Else it returns -1
    time_obj = -1
    try:
        time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, '%H:%M:%S')
    except:
        pass

    return time_obj

def compute_opening_duration(opening_time, closing_time):

    #Parse open and close time
    ot = parse_time(opening_time)
    ct = parse_time(closing_time)
    #If either of them is -1, return -1
    print('the opening time is: %s' %opening_time)
    print('the closing time is: %s' %closing_time)
    if ct == -1 or ot == -1:
        return -1
    #Else return time difference in hours
    else:
        dateTimeDifference = ct - ot
        dateTimeDifferenceInHours = dateTimeDifference.total_seconds() / 3600
        print('the opening duration is: %d' %dateTimeDifferenceInHours)
```

Here data_dict is a dictionary which is created from the .csv file and Open and Close are two numpy arrays containing opening time and closing time respectively.

The opening time and the closing time are in the form 'Hour:Minute:Second'.
If the opening time or the closing time are not in the correct form, the function returns -1.

Example:

opening time: '8:30:00', closing time: '16:00:00', return 7.5

opening time: '9:00:00', closing time: '16:15:00', return 7.25

opening time: '8:30:00', closing time: 'evening', return -1

The code mentioned doesn't compute the opening duration for all the elements in the array automatically and the values in `compute_opening_duration()`
need to be mentioned my me, eg. ('14:00:00','16:00:00')
. I'm looking for a solution with which the function takes the values (times) directly from the arrays and convert the output into an array as well.

Comment: Not sure why you deleted that question, but please provide the update to the question I asked in the old question

Comment: Do you know about [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org). Using this package you can get all you want; You will need to use `pandas.read_csv`, `pandas.to_datetime` helper functions and substruct two columns each other...

Answer (score 1):

To do this I just iterated through the list of open and closing times and put the results of your functions into another array to return. If the array sizes do not match the function returns -1 similar to your functions.

Here is the code:

```
def compute_hours_array(open_times, close_times):
 # parameters are arrays. 
 operating_hours = []
 if len(open_times) == len(close_times):
  for k in range(len(open_times)):
   operating_hours.append(compute_opening_duration(open_times[k],close_times[k]))
   return operating_hours
  return -1
```

Hope that helps.